# How to skip layout with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  layout :check_layout

  def check_layout
    return nil if request.xhr?
    'application'
  end
end
```

Devise ignores this condition and renders layout.
How to fix?

// upd

Now trying in config/application.rb - still ignores for sign_in and sign_up ;(

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout nil
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout nil
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout false` to render no layout.

`layout nil` will force default layout behavior with inheritance.

Comment: Oh, rly. I am so bad. Thanks you. :)